# Windows 8 lowers volume on using any software that involves the microphone

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, microphone

**This is not affected by *Do nothing* in *Sound* > *Communication* tab.**

So everytime I open a software that may involve microphone usage, my playback volume is automatically lowered.

Easily reproducible by starting either *Audio Recorder*, *Recording* tab in the *Sound* window (This is instantly, switching to another tab restores the volume) or playing a game like Dota 2 (which has ingame voice chat).

I have disabled any effects for the speaker I use under *Properties* > *Enhancements* and unticked the checkboxes under the *Advanced* tab.

**Observation 1:** When opening the volume control and the *Sound* window, the actual controls for the speakers, etc. don't move, but the levels get lower.

**Observation 2:** When starting Dota 2, the sound is only quiet when I load into an actual game, not earlier.